# How to find all dependencies of a cell in Excel (also conditional formatting and data validation)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to cleanup a very complex Excel file.

To be able to erase a cell, I need to make sure it's not used somewhere in the workbook. 
I know it is possible to find out if a cell is used in another cell's formula by going in *Formula auditing > Trace dependents* but this does not work if the cell is used in the following contexts :

- Part of a range used for a drop-down list in the *Data validation* of another cell
- In a formula part of the *Conditional formatting* of another cell.

These 2 Excel features are used a lot in the workbook.

Do you know a way to found out those dependencies ?

Comment: I suspect that you might need a brute-force approach of creating a collection of all such ranges and checking if a given cell is contained in any of them. You might also need to worry if the cell in question is part of some named range.

Comment: This is impossible if the spreadsheet contains things like INDIRECT and OFFSET. Not sure if even VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP dependencies show up. Then there are chart references to worry about too.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I already removed those functions for performance issues. So, I don't need to worry about that...

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this, not 100%, but looks like it works from simple tests

```
Sub DependantTest()

For Each i In DependantOnValidation(Range("A1"))

    Debug.Print i

Next i

End Sub
```

Using this function

```
Function DependantOnValidation(rngLookAt As Excel.Range) As Collection

Dim ws As Worksheet Dim rInspect As Range Dim rWorking As Range Dim rIntersect As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

On Error Resume Next

Set DependantOnValidation = New Collection

For Each rInspect In ws.Range("a1:z1")

    Set rWorking = Range(Replace(rInspect.Validation.Formula1, "=", vbNullString))

    If Not rWorking Is Nothing Then

        Set rIntersect = Application.Intersect(rngLookAt, rWorking)
        DependantOnValidation.Add rInspect.Address

    End If

    Set rWorking = Nothing
     Next rInspect

End Function
```

and for CF something like this, not complete tho

```
If rInspect.FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
    For Each fCondition In rInspect.FormatConditions
        If fCondition.Formula1 <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, fCondition.Formula1, rngLookAt.Address(True, True)) > 0 Or _
                    InStr(1, fCondition.Formula1, rngLookAt.Address(False, True)) > 0 Or _
                        InStr(1, fCondition.Formula1, rngLookAt.Address(True, False)) > 0 Then

            End If
        End If
    Next fCondition
End If
```

Comment: Seems like it should solve half of the question nicely. Can you extend it to conditional formatting?

Comment: For conditional formatting, it's actually more complicated. When the condition applies to a range with a relative formula, the address that appears in the condition formula of the entire range is the one relative to the top left cell of the range. (hard to explain) Anyways, for the data validation, with small corrections and changes, your code works great. It will be enough for now for most of my problems 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should edit @Nathan_Sav answer with my corrections or post my corrected version as a new answer... I'm quite new...